# Magento JOIN between two filtered custom collections

Tags: php, magento, join, collections, filtering

I've two custom models **("myorder" and "myarticle")**.
Each "`myarticle`" has a foreign key "`rif_ord_app`" that points to the related "`myorder`" field "`rif_ordine_vsp`". 
I need to filter both collections and then JOIN them using the two fields "`rif_ord_app`" and "`rif_ordine_vsp`".

For example:

I filter "myorders" collection:

```
$collection_orders = Mage::getModel('mycomp_logistic/myorder')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('customer_id', array('in' => array_values($arrayCustomersId)))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('payment_done_online', array('eq' => ($filter['is_from_where'] == 'from_web')))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('pdv_ritiro_id', array('eq' => $filter['pdv_ritiro_code']))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('pdv_ordinante_id', array('eq' => $filter['pdv_ordinante_code']))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('rif_ordine_vsp', array('eq' => $filter['num_ord']))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('data_ordine', array('from' => $daydate));
```

...then I filter "myarticle" collection:

```
$collection_articles = Mage::getModel('mycomp_logistic/myarticle')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('num_bolla', array('eq' => $filter['cod_bolla']))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('sscc', array('eq' => $filter['sscc']))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('stato', array('eq' => $filter['st_art']));
```

..and finally...I didn't manage to JOIN the two collections.

I tried something like this:

```
$tbl_order = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('mycomp_logistic/myorder');
$collection_articles = $collection_articles->getSelect()->join(array('t2' => $tbl_order), 'main_table.rif_ord_app = t2.rif_ordine_vsp', 't2.rif_ordine_vsp');
```

..but I'm sure that is the wrong way.

Any help?

Comment: check: joinField($alias, $table, $field, $bind, $cond=null, $joinType=’inner’) method. http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/using_collections_in_magento

Comment: I assume you really need 2 EAV models ? beacause it would be easier with flat models.

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to use DDL, you must make the Join and apply the filters after that... You cant join 2 filtered collection to generate 1 collection